# Problem capturing data inside of a capture that is optional

Tags: ruby, regex

It's best to start with an example and what I've gotten so far.

Sample Data:

```
FOO foo@acme.com 5545
<Data><Name>tester</Name><Foo>bar</Foo></Data>
```

Current regex:

```
/FOO\s(.{1,20}@[^\s]+)\s.{0,20}\s{1,2}(<Data>.{0,100}<Name>(.{0,20})<\/Name>.{0,100}<\/Data>)?/m
```

Matches from regex:

1. foo@acme.com
2. testerbar
3. tester

I've wrapped the `<Data>` section in parenthesis followed-by a `?` because the entire data section may or may not exist. However, the `<Name>` section is also optional, it may or may not exist. So I tried putting parenthesis around `<Name>` with a question mark as well but then I don't get the matches:

```
/FOO\s(.{1,20}@[^\s]+)\s.{0,20}\s{1,2}(<Data>.{0,100}(<Name>(.{0,20})<\/Name>)?.{0,100}<\/Data>)?/m
```

I've posted my regex and sample data on a regex site to make it easier to test/validate what I'm trying to do: http://www.rubular.com/r/ZhQzlNp1vv

In the `<Data>` section there is `<Name>` and even `<Foo>`. The point is, there may be many different elements in `<Data>` and I only care about extracting data from some of them. I need to use regex for my particular situation so please don't suggest using some XML parsing library (thanks!).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So the desired output is: 1. foo@acme.com 2. tester?

Comment: @duane - Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/FOO\s(\S+@\S+).*?\n(?:.{0,100}(.{0,20})</Name>.{0,100}</Data>)?/m

http://www.rubular.com/r/IhisH7HYJR

Comment: thanks, guess that makes sense because the entire Data portion was optional.

Answer (score 1):

To capture an optional group, use a non-capturing group to indicate the optionality inside a capturing group.

i.e.

```
((?:content)?)
```

The outer parentheses form the capturing group - if the optional group doesn't match you get an empty string. The `(?:`...`)` is the non-capturing group, which allows you to group the content (so it can all be made optional) without capturing it.

**Update:**
Whenever you have a complex regex, use free-spacing comment mode (flag=x) to make it readable (and thus far easier to figure out what's going on), like this:

```
FOO\s(.{1,20}@[^\s]+)\s.{0,20}\s{1,2}

((?:<Data>
    # upto 200 chars, excluding captured tags or end tag (repeated below)
    (?:(?!<Name>|<Foo>|<Bob>|<\/Data>).){0,200}

    # Capture 3:
    ((?:<Name>.{0,20}<\/Name>)?)

    (?:(?!<Name>|<Foo>|<Bob>|<\/Data>).){0,200}

    # Capture 4:
    ((?:<Foo>.{0,20}<\/Foo>)?)

    (?:(?!<Name>|<Foo>|<Bob>|<\/Data>).){0,200}

    # Capture 5:
    ((?:<Bob>.{0,20}<\/Bob>)?)

    (?:(?!<Name>|<Foo>|<Bob>|<\/Data>).){0,200}
<\/Data>)?)
```

Which at [rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/Jnc1vtygkg) results in:

```
1. foo@acme.com
2. <Data><Name>tester</Name><Foo>bar</Foo></Data>
3. <Name>tester</Name>
4. <Foo>bar</Foo>
5.
```

Annoyingly rubular doesn't seem to provide a multi-line editor when x is turned on, which sucks, and it also doesn't support standard comment syntax, so I had to change those `#...` to `(?#...)` which is less readable. Oh well.

If you need the values without the tags, you'll need a separate expression to strip those.
( Or, y'know, use a tool actually designed for the job. ;) )

Comment: I think I applied what you suggested, http://www.rubular.com/r/hv1XDFAcZa, but it's not giving me the output I expect.

Comment: Well you're running into the reasons why trying to parse XML with regex isn't a great idea, and you really should look at tools more suited to the job (yeah, I know you said "I need to use regex", but "need" is relative).

However, have a look at my edit...

Comment: thanks for the tip on the comments, that's much nicer to read.